# How to modify a struct field inside closure via a raw pointer?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have following code of a thread proc called from C code. `context` is a pointer to a struct on heap `(Box::into_raw(Box::new(...))`. The closure is passed to `add_callback` function and stored in a vector of callbacks, to be called later from another function. How can I modify the fields of the `app_context` inside the closure?

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn worker_thread_proc(context: *mut c_void) -> c_int {
    unsafe {
        let app_context = context as *mut AppContext;

        let my_closure = Rc::new(|a: N, _, _, _| {
            (*app_context).foo = 0; // HOW TO DO THIS PROPERLY?
            0
        });

        // save the closure to a Vec in an object

        ...
   }
}
```

Attempting to code it straight way leads to error which can be understood, since `app_context` is being borrowed by the closure.

```
error[E0597]: `app_context` does not live long enough

...
}
- `app_context` dropped here while still borrowed
```

However I know that the object pointed to by the raw pointer will continue to be valid even after the `worker_thread_proc` function has finished. How can I achieve my desired goal to modify the state of my context structure in such case?

I've tried to use `Rc` on the pointer and clone it before use, but that also gives `does not live long enough` error. I believe there should also be some way to do it via `Box` but I couldn't figure it out myself.

**UPDATE: Added a MRE**

```
use std::ffi::c_void;
use std::ptr;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct AppContext {
    ctx: *mut Ctx,
    foo: u32
}

pub struct Native(pub Rc<dyn Fn(N, N, N, N) -> N>);

pub enum N {
    FuncNativeDef(Native),
    Unit
}

pub struct Ctx {
    pub values: Vec<N>
}

impl Ctx {
    pub fn new() -> Ctx {
        Ctx {
            values: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn set_val(&mut self, name: &str, n: N) {
        self.values.push(n);
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn worker_thread_proc(context: *mut c_void) {
    unsafe {
        let app_context = context as *mut AppContext;
        let mut ctx = &mut *(*app_context).ctx;

        let my_closure = Rc::new(|a: N, _, _, _| {
            (*app_context).foo = 2;
            N::Unit
        });

        ctx.set_val("my_closure", N::FuncNativeDef(Native(my_closure)));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let context = Box::new(AppContext{
        foo: 42,
        ctx: Box::into_raw(Box::new(Ctx::new()))
    });

    let context_ptr = Box::into_raw(context);
}
```

Comment: nit: you don't need an `unsafe` block that wraps the whole body of an `unsafe` function, if you want to use them inside then wrap only the unsafe code (here both pointer dereferences), an `unsafe` block that wraps the whole body doesn't add any info and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more minimal example demonsrating the same problem:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_void;

struct AppContext {
    ctx: Option<Box<dyn Fn()>>,
    foo: u32,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn worker_thread_proc(context: *mut c_void) {
    let app_context = context as *mut AppContext;
    let ctx = unsafe { &mut (*app_context).ctx };

    let my_closure = Box::new(|| {
        unsafe { (*app_context).foo = 2 };
    });

    *ctx = Some(my_closure);
}
```

the problem is that to dereference a pointer all you need is a reference to it, but that means the closure can (and therefore will) take `app_context` by reference, which then leads to the compiler erroring with

```
error[E0597]: `app_context` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
13 |     let my_closure = Box::new(|| {
   |                              -- value captured here
14 |         unsafe { (*app_context).foo = 2 };
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 |     *ctx = Some(my_closure);
   |                 ---------- cast requires that `app_context` is borrowed for `'static`
18 | }
   | - `app_context` dropped here while still borrowed
```

To solve it you can force the compiler to copy the pointer `app_context` by using the `move` keyword:

```
let my_closure = Box::new(move || { /*…*/ });
```

You have to be very careful with this though. Moving this struct, which is the default in Rust will dangle that `app_context` pointer and calling the closure afterwards will invoke UB!

Comment: I don't see how the number of arguments or the type of the smart pointer would change anything here.